# Hacer especie de SELECT con condicion IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: batch

Quiero hacer un Script que solo copipe una sola vez un archivo si este Existe no volver a copiar o crear **pero si o si en .bat (Batch)**
el archivo se llama:

```
TestBackUp.rar
```

esta en el discoduro en la siguiente URL

```
C:\BackUP\TestBackUp.rar
```

deseo se copie si en l siguiente URL NO existe

```
D:\BackUP\TestBackUp.rar
```

EL codigo en SQL seria algo como por ejemplo:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TestBackUp.rar)
COPY
ELSE
NO COPY
```

Este es un pequeño trozo de lo que tengo adelantado:

```
    @echo off
:: aqui condicion IF no existe dentro del directorio D:\BackUP\TestBackUp.rar
echo Buscando y comprimiendo desde WinRaR en 32 y 64 Bits 
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" A -R D:\BackUp\TestBackUp.RAR "C:\BackUp\Patch" 
cls 
echo Buscando y comprimiendo desde WinRaR en 32
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" A -R D:\BackUp\TestBackUp.RAR "C:\BackUp\Patch" 
::Fin de condicion

cls 
rd /s /q "C:\BackUp" 
move C:\Temporal\BackUp\*.RAR D:\BackUp  
cls 
rd /s /q "C:\Temporal" 
echo. 
    ::de lo contrario

    cls 
    rd /s /q "C:\BackUp" 
    move C:\Temporal\BackUp\*.RAR D:\BackUp  
    cls 
    rd /s /q "C:\Temporal" 
    echo. 
    Exit
```

Comment: No entiendo. SQL es para consultar datos, no para copiar archivos. ¿Puedes explicar a qué viene el SQL en tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿te sirvió de algo la respuesta?

Comment: Utilizar SQL en esta pregunta hace que sea enrevesada de entener. No es el mejor ejemplo del mundo...

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) funciona para chequear la existencia de archivos ti se utiliza en la siguiente sintaxis:

```
IF [NOT] EXIST filename (command) ELSE (command)
```

Por otro lado, te sugiero utilizar etiquetas (`:Etiqueta` y `GOTO Etiqueta` y/o `CALL :Etiqueta` con `Goto :EOF` ) para definir el flujo del programa mejor que sentencias dentro del if (Por ejemplo, %Errorlevel% no se "pasa" dentro y fuera del If, y otros comportamientos similares).